# Problema al conectar una clase php con una base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, php5

Lo que quiero hacer es conectar a una base de datos MySQL con una clase PHP, la cual automáticamente establezca la conexión y realice las 
respectivas consultas:

```
<?php
  class Connection extends mysqli{
    //Connection data
    private $DB_NAME = "datos";
    private $DB_TABLE = "user";
    private $DB_HOST = "localhost";
    private $DB_PASSWORD = "password";
    private $DB_USER = "root";
    public $DB_CHARSET = "utf8";

    //Constructor
    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct($this->DB_HOST,$this->DB_USER,$this->$DB_PASSWORD,$this->DB_NAME);
      if ($this->connect_errno) echo "<div class='mensaje'>Error:
        {$this->connect_errno} -> {$this->connect_error}</div>";
      $this->set_charset($this->$DB_CHARSET);
    }

    //Insert new record
    public function insert($id,$name,$password){
      $sql_comand = "INSERT INTO {$this->DB_TABLE} VALUES (?,?,?)";
      if(!($sentence = $this->prepare($sql_comand))){
        echo "Error(prepare): {$this->connect_errno} -> {$this->connect_error}";
      }
      $sentence = $this->bind_param("iss",$id,$name,$password);
      $sentence->execute();
    }
  }

  $conexion = new Connection();
?>
```

Pero al momento de tratar instanciar la clase, me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me parece más raro es que cuando intento hacer la conexión sin utilizar la clase, no me sale ningún error y todo funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que retorna es de permiso de usuario y es por que tienes el '$DB_PASSWORD' de la conexión con el caractér '$'. Debes sacarlo y depaso el caractér '$' que tienes en $DB_CHARSET porque también te va a retornar error. Debe quedar así:

```
public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct($this->DB_HOST,$this->DB_USER,$this->DB_PASSWORD,$this->DB_NAME);
      if ($this->connect_errno) echo "<div class='mensaje'>Error:
        {$this->connect_errno} -> {$this->connect_error}</div>";
      $this->set_charset($this->DB_CHARSET);
    }
```

De paso, y como sugerencia, sería muy bueno incorporar  try{}catch() para capturar los errores.